# Secondary click toggle in OS X

Tags: cocoa, macos, accessibility

I'm trying to write a program that serves to toggle a secondary click for a one button HID (in this case a touch screen). What I want to do is have the user touch a button on the screen that makes the next touch a right click. I simply don't know where to begin on this. I began by looking to Applescript, but found that this is impossible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe that's possible by simulation a pressed down ctrl key.

Comment: That was my initial idea, but, from what I know and can find out about Applescript, modifier keys (e.g. control, option) cannot be independently handled. I can say press s with control down, but not just control down. The other issue I ran into was having that script run for the next click only. I don't think mouse events can be detected by Applescript.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for OS X's [event tap mechanism](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html). Event taps are used to find and modify low level events.

In your app you would set an event tap to find mouse down events and insert key down/up events into the event stream for the modifier keys where neccessary.

Comment: Or even change the type of event from a left-mouse-down/-dragged/-up to a right-mouse-down/-dragged/-up. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventSetType and http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGEventType .